# Cannot GET /blah.html - .ejs can't load html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm using Nodejs and Express to create a dynamic webpage.

I have a `home.ejs` file that has this iframe:

```
<iframe id="newstable" src="/news_tables/2018-08-04.html" height="1000" width="100%"></iframe>
```

My folder directory is:

```
News_Aggregator (includes app.js)
News_Aggregator/news_tables (includes a bunch of html files, e.g. `2018-08-04.html`)
News_Aggregator/views (includes my `home.ejs` file)
```

And my `app.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('home.ejs');
});

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8000!')
});
```

However, when `home.ejs` is rendered, my iframe doesn't load the `html` page:

[image]

This works in "normal" HTML.  What am I missing to get the `.ejs` file to find this and render correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You get the error because the server dosen't know where to get the files from. 
First You must define where the static .ejs files will be. Lets say something like this. if your files are in a public folder(ejs,css etc) and you will get them from there. Setup both with:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/public'));
```

from here you can just in your response if you have a home.ejs file

```
  res.render('home', {});
```

You should look over Express `static()` from [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and learn how to serve files

Comment: I'll look in to this for sure, but quick question: That frame I'm trying to load could be any of 100 html pages.  Would I have to serve *each one* of those specifically? Or just set up the folder they're in?

Comment: Well if you have let say 100  iframes inside a .ejs file you should pass a list of file names to the render file which will be used in the .ejs file. Something like this: `res.render('template.ejs',{list: listOfFilePath})` and in .ejs file do a foreach for each of `listOfFilePath` and render an iframe for each.

Comment: It's not that I have 100 iframes to show in the ejs, it's the iframe could be one of 100 different ones.  The user can click a list, and depending on that `li` value, the iframe loads the html for that item. I'm looking in to `static()` now

Answer (score 1):

The fact your HTML is generated from a `.ejs` file is irrelevant.

Your HTML says the browser should ask the server for the URL `/news_tables/2018-08-04.html`.

Your HTTP server has a route `app.get('/',` and **no other routes**.

Your HTTP server doesn't know about the URL `/news_tables/2018-08-04.html`, so it returns a `404 Not Found`.

You need to write code which will serve up all the URLs you want it to.

You should probably look at the Express `static()` middleware if you want to serve static files.

Comment: Aha, this makes sense. I'm looking in to the static method, but can't quite understand how they link.  I kept my `ejs` file the same, but added `app.use(express.static('news_tables'))` but it still says cannot GET.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works is removing ".html" from address "localhost:3000/index.html".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30616786)